# remove Top Fragment of BackStack

Tags: android, android-fragments

What I am trying to do is at `onBackPressed` I want create a new object of the top Fragment so I am trying this code:

```
if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
    FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backEntry =getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()-1);
    String Back_fragment_name=backEntry.getName();
    if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag1")){
        Frag1 frag = new Frag();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag1").commit();
    }else if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag2")){
        Frag2 frag = new Frag2();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag2").commit();
    }else if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag3")){
        Frag3 frag = new Frag3();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag3").commit();
    }
    //getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); //Wrong
} else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

The problem is I think I should then remove the Top Fragment from BackStack but using `popBackStack` is wrong because it shows the the top fragment and i only need to remove it from BackStack.

any Ideas?

Comment: First of all get fragment using id or tag Fragment fragment1 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (tag);
and then remove fragment using getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag)

Comment: `beginTransaction().remove(frag) ` will remove the fragment from Activity but not from BackStack

Comment: @AtefHares - Not sure if this is what you need exactly.. Try this - int backStackCount = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        
            //Get backstack fragment id
            int backStackId = mFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(backStackCount -1).getId();
            mFragmentManager.popBackStack(backStackId, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: Using backstack position of fragment  
fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentPosition).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad, No that is not what I want, I want at `onBackPressed` instead of showing the same Instance of top fragment i want to create a new Instance.

Comment: @P.Rai, Could u explain more, i want to create a new Frag not to use the Backstack Instance

Comment: @AtefHares - First pop the top fragment and then create a new instance..

Comment: Add fragment without adding it to backstack

Comment: @YasirTahir, But I want to implement the `onBackPressed` behavior of returning to previous fragment

Comment: What do you want to implement? Please explain the complete scenario

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad, I did what u said and It shows the PoPed Instance below the new Frag instance.

Comment: @YasirTahir, I have a navigation Viewer with Navigation Menu of 3 Items each transacts a `fragment`, I want to Implement `onBackPressed` behavior of showing the previous fragment but not showing it's BackStack Instance but instead I want to create a new one, do you understand me, Sir?

Comment: And you have to keep your backstack filled?

Comment: According to google design pattern, Navigation Bar should be implemented in a Parent Child hierarchy. Which means that, all of the Navigation menu items are always on the top without any backstack item. You if you open any fragment from navigation bar, it should be the only fragment present in the backstack. And this way everytime, a new fragment will be added removing all of the previously added fragments. Please read more about this at https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns

Comment: @YasirTahir, i am only using `addToBackStack` to know what are previous fragments  in order to create the Correct new Instance but i don't need the fragments's Instances which added to it

Comment: @PoojaGaikwad, Invalid index, throwIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @AtefHares - sorry buddy.. This is working at my end.. I will try for more solutions if possible :)

Comment: @Pooja Gaikwad, thanks for ur effort

Comment: @Yasir Tahir, thanks for ur efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to do is to implement the `onBackPressed`, that is pressing back button will transact the previous fragment, But I did not want to transact the previous Instance but a new one so I was using the Question's code. to do that I was adding fragments to BackStack in order to know which fragment is previous [the top one of the Backstack] then creating a new instance of it. So i was getting it's name then create it's new instance then delete it from the BackStack [Thats was the problem, I could not be able to delete it from backstack].

**Finally** I figured out that I do not need to use BackStack at All to know what are the previous fragments I just used an `ArrayList` of `String` to save every transacted Fragment's Name or tag so for example when transacting `Frag1` I do this:

```
Frag1 frag1 = new Frag1 ();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.RR, frag1 , "frag1").commit();
mPreviousFragmentsNames.add("frag1");
```

and `onBackPressed` will be like this:

```
if(!Removed_Last_Fragment_Name_From_backList){
 // a boolean value, removing this will cause a bad behavior
 // that is if back button pressed it transact current shown fragment first then u need to press back again to go to previous one
 mPreviousFragmentsNames.remove(mPreviousFragmentsNames.size()-1);
 Removed_Last_Fragment_Name_From_backList = true;
}

if (!mPreviousFragmentsNames.isEmpty()) {
    String Back_fragment_name = mPreviousFragmentsNames.get(mPreviousFragmentsNames.size()-1);
  if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag1")){
    Frag1 frag = new Frag();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag1").commit();
  }else if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag2")){
    Frag2 frag = new Frag2();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag2").commit();
  }else if(Back_fragment_name.equals("Frag3")){
    Frag3 frag = new Frag3();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.RR, frag , "Frag3").commit();
  }
} else{
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and It works Great, as Needed !

Comment: I suggested you not to use backstack while adding/replacing fragment :D

Comment: Ya u did, but u didn't give me an alternative way to do what i wanted :), any way Thanks for help